# Can't get gamma right in Windows. In Ubuntu it's very good by default

Tags: drivers, colors, calibration, icc

I'm having a hard time adjusting my monitor's gamma to my liking in Windows.

I'm not a photographer/video editor or anything like that, I don't need precise calibration, but the default settings 
in Windows with my graphics hardware and monitor are just WAY off it actually hurts my eyes.

Although this miscalibration is obvious just looking at the desktop (gray lines on the icons of text files aren't 
visible), a quick look at [this](http://www.lagom.nl/lcd-test/) page confirms that gamma is way off. Under the gamma 
calibration section the 48% images "blend in" at gamma 1.3.

In Ubuntu 14.04, interestingly, with default settings it is great.

I have a HP Envy 15 notebook, which has a Intel HD 4600 and a Nvidia 840M.

The first thing I tried was to fiddle with the settings in the Intel graphics control panel, but even turning gamma and
contrast all the way down still results in the 48% images blending at 1.9 while the 10% images are barely visible because
the screen goes too dark. I tried all combinations of settings in the Intel driver, but I can't get it right this way.

The Nvidia driver doesn't have color settings and later I disabled it in device manager to make sure it doesn't affect
the screen colors.

Interestingly the colors are off even when booting Windows in safe mode, where neither driver is loaded, I suppose.

I also tried loading the icc profile used in Ubuntu into Windows, but it doesn't do anything. I then downloaded a test
icc profile, which should result in crazy color shifts, to test if the profile is even loaded.
I followed [these](https://pcmonitors.info/articles/using-icc-profiles-in-windows/) steps to load the profile and I also 
disabled the igfxpers.exe in msconfig, since some people reported this to mess with icc profiles.
Since all this didn't do anything, I disabled all Intel and Nvidia related things in msconfig, still without success.

Now I pretty much don't know what to do anymore. I'm very grateful for all suggestions.

Comment: Some image editors come with an on-screen adjustment tool.  For example, Photoshop has one to adjust each color and then the profile is loaded at startup.  IIRC, theirs is called Adobe Gamma Loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd invest in a cheap-ish colorimiter - even a Huey Pro [discontinued, look on eBay] or ColorMunki Smile would be less painful than trying to do it yourself.

There are better, no doubt there may be worse, but those are 2 cheaper ones I've tried with reasonable success

Comment: I'm on the verge of doing that but I fear that it might not help, since Windows can't be bothered to load any ICC profile - and wouldn't the same just happen to the profile created by the calibration process?

Comment: I have used both those devices on Mac [up to Yosemite] & PC [up to Win 7] (never tried nix) quite successfully. Only dropped the Huey when the software became incompatible on Mac. idk how it pushes its way into the system ICC profile space, but it does, quite successfully. Your question actually prompted me to go round recalibrating everything today, in fact :)

Comment: I'd take a look at a [colourhug](http://www.hughski.com/) - officially uses a livecd, but http://dispcalgui.hoech.net/ supports ot, its open hardware, and only about UKP 60 + shipping. I've been looking at getting one myself at some point.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - for me, it's something I'll buy once… or until it's no longer supported, which happened with my Huey [damn thing still works on Windows, just not Mac] In the long-run, I'd have been better off getting an expensive one, still supported, rather than 2 cheap ones, but who's to know ;) tbh, most of us will never need a high-end device, as we don't need to balance camera to screen to print, we just don't want eye-strain.

Answer (score 0):

To conclude this thread, I'll tell what I ended up doing. I did get a colormeter and calibrated the notebook display - and all others I own. The results on the notebook display are OK. The colors are much better and gamma also slightly improved. It may just be the best that can be achieved with this display and I can live with how it is currently. The results on other monitors of mine are great, however, and I'm not unhappy that I got the colormeter.

Comment: Out of interest, which did you get?

Comment: I got a Spyder 4. They sold several variations of this and the ColorMunki Display and a whole bunch of meters ranging up to over 1000 francs.